# Как просмотреть файлы из сетевой папки на CentOS без монтирования

Tags: php, centos

Уважаемые знатоки. Задался следующим вопросом:
Можно ли просматривать файлы/каталоги в **CentOS (Sabma+Apache+PHP)** без монтирования папки?
Если папку монтировать так:
`//192.168.0.11/share /media/sharefolder cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`
то все работает замечательно. Можно смонтировать, посмотреть, и отключиться (*PHP-скрипт все смотрит и все видит*).
Поскольку сама шара находится на **Windows-сервере DFS**, и доступ туда по логину\паролю: с методом выше работает штатно. Но хочется сделать как в Windows - ввел ссылку в проводник `//192.168.0.11/share` (авторизовался) и вот вам файлы. Проводник закрыл - и нет больше соединения. Монтировать ничего не пришлось.
Что мы имеем:

1. Сервер Samba+Apache+PHP
2. Файл с логином-паролем учетки, которая имеет право смотреть файлы.
3. Желание разобраться

**Что по факту я хочу получить:** 
Я ввожу в форму сайта сетевой путь `//192.168.0.11/share` и PHP-скрипт у меня смотрит файлы именно по этому пути и отдает мне список.
Если есть возможность напрямую делать это средствами PHP/CentOS - буду только рад.
**Почему не хочу использовать монтирование:**

1. Может быть много путей с одинаковым окончанием `//192.168.0.11/share` и `//192.168.100.11/share`
2. При монтировании мне нужно заботиться о том, чтобы имя было уникально
3. Нужно следить за тем, отмонтирована ли шара
4. Если она не отмонтировалась, периодически чистить руками, что не очень хочется.

Comment: Ну то есть вся задача как всегда получается из детской веры в чудеса - если виндоус, как обычно совершает совершенно стандартные операции, но скрывает их от пользовтеля, то значит этих действий как бы и нету, и все происходит по влошебству.

Comment: @Ипатьев Смотря как на это посмотреть. Винда если делает тоже самое, но скрывает это - то можно сказать что это "действие из коробки" или "стандартные средства". Соответственно ведь могут быть подобные "стандартные средства" и в *nix системах, о которых, лично я -  могу не знать/не найти, о чем и задаю свой вопрос.  Если есть готовые методы, зачем изобретать велосипед заново. (А чтобы правильно найти эти методы, нужно правильно знать как они называется, иначе по умолчанию можно считать, что готового никогда и ничего не существует, и каждый раз что-то изобретать).